# How to use sceneform.asset() in Android Studio with build.gradle.kts?

Tags: android, android-studio, augmented-reality, sceneform

How to use sceneform.asset() in Android Studio with build.gradle.kts

[image]

It throws exception:  Unresolved reference: sceneform

With build.gradle (groovy) in works perfectly

[image]